# Open curly braces should be opened in the same line of if statement, for loops, methods, etc

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, powershell-2.0

Suppose i have code snippet like:

```
if(some condition)
{
some code here;
}
else if (some other condition)
{
some more code;
}
public static some_method(something passed here maybe) 
{
some other code;
}
```

Then it should get formatted to:

```
if(some condition) {
some code here;
} else if (some other condition) {
some more code;
}
public static some_method(something passed here maybe) {
some other code;
}
```

This is just example code. I want to run sed script for whole file containing "if statements, for loops, methods, etc." maybe similar or in different formats. So mostly the purpose of the script should be to move these open curly braces one line up. Thanks in advance..

Comment: My recommendation would be not to implement this yourself, and to use an existing prettifier tool for the language you are writing.

Comment: @TomFenech - I respect your suggestion, but those beautifier/prettifier tools only feasible for 2-3 files. If you have hundreads/thousands of files you cant go ahead and waste whole day(s) going through files one by one, that's if we have some script then we can loop through that script and work on all the files in one attempt.

Comment: I would be very surprised if any tool you downloaded didn't support prettifying more than one file per invocation, and if it does, then you can always write a simple `for` loop or use `find` in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# get input filename ...

filename="${1}"

# Do basic checks (etc) ...
if [[ -z "${filename}" ]]
then
    echo "[ERR] No file name supplied."
    echo "Usage: `basename ${0}` \"the file name\""

    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -f "${filename}" ]]
then
    echo "[ERR] No file named \"${filename}\" exists anywhere."

    exit 1
fi

# Create  "SED crunch script" ...
sedscript="/tmp/sedscript.sed"

cat << EOF > "${sedscript}"

    # if "function syntax found, then read in next line
    # and print, else just print current line ...

    /^.*([^)]*)[ |  ]*$/{

    N

        /^.*([^)]*)[ |  ]*\n[ | ]*{.*$/{

            # Remove newline from first and appended line ...
            s/\n//g

            # ... and print what we have to STDOUT ...
            p

            b skip_default_print
        }

        # Next line did not start with open curly brace,
        # so just print what we currently have and
        # skip default print ..

        p

        b skip_default_print
    }

    p

    :skip_default_print

EOF

# Execute crunch script against code ...
sed -n -f "${sedscript}" "${filename}"
```

Save above script into a bash script. Then execute it like below:
(example below assumes script is saved as crunch.sh)

./crunch.sh "code.java"

... where "code.java" is the code you wish to "crunch". Result is sent to STDOUT.

## Here's input I used:

```
if(some condition)
{
some code here;
}
else if (some other condition)
{
some more code;
}
public static some_method(something passed here maybe) 
{
some other code;
}
```

## And output:

```
if(some condition){
some code here;
}
else if (some other condition){
some more code;
}
public static some_method(something passed here maybe) {
some other code;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. This is working all fine but partially, its working for control statements only not for methods. Could you please check or am i missing something.

Comment: It works perfectly for me ("... he says looking confused"). Here's my input and outputs in the next couple of comments (note that the method itself has also been processed in the output) ...

Comment: if(some condition)
{
some code here;
}
else if (some other condition)
{
some more code;
}
public static some_method(something passed here maybe) 
{
some other code;
}

Comment: if(some condition){
some code here;
}
else if (some other condition){
some more code;
}
public static some_method(something passed here maybe) {
some other code;
}

Comment: ... actually you can't tell through the comments, so I'll add it to my original solution/message posted initially

Comment: Sorry i was not clear i think you misunderstood me, i think this code is looking for parenthesis in the line but i want it to work if it finds a open curly brace in the new line then it should push that one line up.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeating the comment you got from Tom Fenech, especially if the requirements get more complicated:

> My recommendation would be not to implement this yourself, and to use
>   an existing prettifier tool for the language you are writing

But still, here’s a possible solution, but I dont know how well it'll do in the real world. `RS="\n[[:space:]]*{"` splits the input on points where a newline is followed by spaces, tabs etc. before the brace, and then replace that with `' {'`. Saving a line and printing it later avoids adding a final `{` at the end of the output.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { RS="\n[[:space:]]*{"
    NR == 1 {
        line=$0; 
        next 
    } 
    { 
        printf "%s", line" {"; 
        line=$0 
    } 
    END {
        print line
}' _file_with_code_
```

Alternatively, this can be written up as follows, using more `awk` features. This does result in a trailing `{` at the end of the file though, which is removed by the added `sed` program

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        # break record on `\n{`
        RS="\n[[:space:]]*{";
        # replace with `{`
        ORS=" {" 
    } 
    # print for each line
    { print }
' input_file | 
sed '
    # for last line ($), `substitute` trailing `{` with ``
    $ s/{$//
'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But i am not able to run it could you please help, syntax error is coming. I tried running it by saving this code in a .awk file then i ran the command: **awk -f myFile.awk**
do i need to save whole code or is there something missing, i am not sure isn't Begin not getting closed anywhere in first code but again not sure.